# SQL Server : select data from table based on certain timestamp

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table that stores data in a one minute timestamp from each other and I'd like to create a select command, that would fetch data from the :59 minute mark from each hour of a requested period, for example from 01.01.2020 to 01.02.2020.

How could I do this? I attach a sample of data from that table, to which the select command will refer to:

[image: Data]

Comment: *"that would fetch data from the :59 minute mark from each hour"* what does that mean? do you only want data between `xx:59:00` and prior to `xx+1:00:00` for a given value of `xx`? That would be no rows in your sample data, as none occur on the 59th minute. If that *is* what you want, which seems like an odd requirement, what's wrong with the `DATEPART` and `MINUTE` functions? If that isn't what you're after, what *are* you after? What have **you** tried and why didn't it work? Take the time to post your sample data as `text` (preferably DDL and DML statements) and include expected results.

Comment: Are you wanting the last row for each hour within the specified date/time range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this.  In plain language the code says "For the range of start date to end date, select the hourly summary statistics for the test table without skipping any hours."

Table

```
drop table if exists test_table;
go
create table test_table(
  ID        int primary key not null,
  date_dt   datetime,
  INP3D     decimal(4, 3),
  ID_device varchar(20));
```

Data

```
insert test_table(ID, date_dt, INP3D, ID_device) values
(1, '2020-08-21 13:44:34.590', 3.631, 'A1'),
(2, '2020-08-21 13:44:34.590', 1.269, 'A1'),
(3, '2020-08-21 13:44:34.590', 0.131, 'A1'),
(4, '2020-08-21 13:44:34.590', 8.169, 'A1');
--select * from test_table;
insert test_table(ID, date_dt, INP3D, ID_device) values
(5, '2020-08-21 11:44:34.590', 3.631, 'A1'),
(6, '2020-08-21 02:44:34.590', 1.269, 'A1'),
(7, '2020-08-22 11:44:34.590', 0.131, 'A1'),
(8, '2020-08-22 01:44:34.590', 8.169, 'A1');
```

Query

```
declare
  @start_dt         datetime='2020-08-21',
  @end_dt           datetime='2020-08-22';

;with 
hours_cte as (
    select hours_n
    from 
    (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),
            (13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24)) v(hours_n)),
days_cte as (
    select dateadd(d, hours_n-1, @start_dt) calc_day from hours_cte where hours_n<=datediff(d, @start_dt, @end_dt)+1)
select
  dc.calc_day,
  hc.hours_n,
  count(*) row_count,
  isnull(avg(INP3D), 0) inp3d_avg,
  isnull(sum(INP3D+0000.000),0) inp3d_sum
from days_cte dc
     cross join hours_cte hc
     left join test_table t on t.date_dt between dateadd(hour, (hours_n-1), dc.calc_day) 
                                            and dateadd(hour, (hours_n), dc.calc_day) 
group by
  dc.calc_day,
  hc.hours_n
order by
  1,2;
```

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEPART(MINUTE, 'your_datetime') = '59'
```

[Datepart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)